# how to prove $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ are supermartingale.and $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is convergence to -7

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $p \in [0  , \frac{1}{2}] $ and $\eta_{i}$ be i.i.d random variables and $P(\eta_{i}=1)=p$ and $P(\eta_{i}=-1)=1-p$ and $\mathcal F_{n}=\sigma(\eta_{1},\cdots,\eta_{n})$ and $X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\eta_{i}$ and $Y_{n}=X_{T(-7)  \wedge  n}  $ . 
     show that

1) $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and  $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ are supermartingale or matigale or submartingale.

2) $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is almost surely convergence to $-7$.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Wait, you cannot prove that X is a supermartingale?

Comment: @Did.i edit the question I dont know which one is true.

Comment: @Did.can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: $E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[\eta_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]+E[X_n|\mathcal{F}_n]$. What can you figure out about each term? I bet that helps you with the first part of 1. Now what does T mean to you?

Comment: @Henrik..subscript in $Y_{n\in \mathbb N}$ means stopping time.

Comment: I'm trying to help you. What are your thoughts to the above? Do you have a result regarding what happens to martingale/submartingale/supermartingale property when stopped by a stopping time? Is this stopping time a special one (maybe a a hitting time)?

Comment: @Henrik.I know most property about martingale when stopped by a stopping time.actully in this question i don't idea.thanks for help

Comment: So whatever type $X$ is $Y$ will be too. How about my hint above, you haven't responded to that. You need to look careful at which results you got about conditional expectations and make sure you use the words 'independence' and 'measurable' :)

Comment: So you solved it all? :)

Comment: @Henrik.No. only $X_{n}$ I think your right solve this problem . you help me so much and now your right get score of this problem.

Comment: @Henrik. thank you so much for answre. but I toll you iam solved the only $X_{n}$ and $(Y_{n})$ is remined.thank you again

Comment: @pualambagher If $X_n$ is a supermartingale do you have a results in your book/lecture notes on the properties of $X_{n \wedge T}$ for T a stopping time? I'm guessing most likely you do and in that case it is simply invoking that result.

Comment: @Henrik.I know most properties about $X_{n\wedge T}$ for $T$ stopping time

Comment: I don't understand your reply. Use the third paragraph starting with: "One of the basic properties.." of [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)#Martingales_and_stopping_times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP has solved question 1 himself, see the comments.
Regarding question 2:

Let $T(-7)=\inf\{n\geq 1 : X_n\in (-\infty,-7] \}$. Let us first make a quick argument that $P(T(-7)<\infty)=1$ which maybe you know.

By the law of large numbers $X_n/n \to p-(1-p) < 0$ a.s. if $p\in[0,1/2)$ so $X_n \to - \infty$ a.s. giving $P(T(-7)<\infty)=1$. 
For $p=1/2$ it is a (i hope) well known fact that $P(X_n \text{ hits m before -7})=-7/(-7-m) \to 0$ and by monotone convergence $P(T(-7)<\infty)=1-\lim_{m} P(X_n \text{ hits m before -7})=1$.

Then $\lim_{n} Y_{n} = \lim _{n} X_{T(-7)\wedge n} =X_{T(-7)}=-7$ a.s per properties of hitting times.